# Loop through xml elements using ssis script task, insert into sql table using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ssis

I am trying to use SSIS calling a stored procedure to insert the values from a XML file into a SQL Server table, but I am having trouble because there can be multiple elements that I need a loop.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<Order xmlns="wpa-net:2000:Order:xdr:1.0">   
   <OrderHead>   
      <Order>
         <OrderNo>123456</OrderNo>
         <Address>
            <AddressLine>Test Road</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Test2</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Test3</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Test4</AddressLine>
            <PostCode>SE1 1OB</PostCode>
         </Address>   
      </Order>   
      <DespatchLine>
          <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
          <DespatchLineReferences>
             <CustomersOrderReference>012345</CustomersOrderReference>
          </DespatchLineReferences>
          <Product>
             <SuppliersProductCode>00111</SuppliersProductCode>
             <ConsumerUnitCode>1</ConsumerUnitCode>
             <Description>Test product</Description>
          </Product>   
       </DespatchLine>   
       <DespatchLine>
          <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
          <DespatchLineReferences>
             <CustomersOrderReference>012345</CustomersOrderReference>
          </DespatchLineReferences>
          <Product>
             <SuppliersProductCode>00111</SuppliersProductCode>
             <ConsumerUnitCode>1</ConsumerUnitCode>
             <Description>Test product</Description>
          </Product>   
       </DespatchLine>   
       <DespatchLine>
          <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
          <DespatchLineReferences>
             <CustomersOrderReference>012345</CustomersOrderReference>
          </DespatchLineReferences>
          <Product>
             <SuppliersProductCode>00111</SuppliersProductCode>
             <ConsumerUnitCode>1</ConsumerUnitCode>
             <Description>Test product</Description>
          </Product>  
       </DespatchLine>   
   </OrderHead> 
</Order>
```

The issue I am having is that the file can contain a number of `DespatchLine` elements, in the example above there is 3 however the number of lines on a order could vary. So far I have managed to insert data but I cant get it to loop through the despatchline elements.

```
public void Main()
{
    //Set Reference to database class
    WriteToDatabase db = new WriteToDatabase();

    string filename = Dts.Variables["xmlTest"].Value.ToString();
    //MessageBox.Show(filename);

    XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    XmlNodeList xmlnode;

    //XmlNodeList xmlnodeDespatchReference;
    int i = 0;
    string str = null;

    string orderNo = "";
    string buyerAddressLine1 = "";
    string buyerAddressLine2 = "";
    string buyerAddressLine3 = "";
    string buyerAddressLine4 = "";
    string buyerPostCode = "";
    string lineNumber = "";
    string customersOrderReference = "";
    string suppliersProductCode = "";
    string consumerUnitCode = "";
    string description = "";

    // Open the filestream
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    //Load the XML file for reading
    xmldoc.Load(fs);

    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);

    string nameSpace = (@"urn:wpa-net:2000:Order:xdr:1.0");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", nameSpace);

    xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Order");

    for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        orderNo = "";
        buyerAddressLine1 = "";
        buyerAddressLine2 = "";
        buyerAddressLine3 = "";
        buyerAddressLine4 = "";
        buyerPostCode = "";
        lineNumber = "";
        customersOrderReference = "";
        suppliersProductCode = "";
        consumerUnitCode = "";
        description = "";

        // OrderNo
        XmlNodeList xmlOrderNodes = xmlnode[i].SelectSingleNode("descendant::ns:Order", nsmgr).ChildNodes;

        foreach (XmlNode xmlOrderNode in xmlOrderNodes)
        {
            switch (xmlOrderNode.Name)
            {
                case "OrderNo":
                    orderNo = xmlOrderNode.InnerText;
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Address
        XmlNodeList xmlAddressNodes = xmlnode[i].SelectSingleNode("descendant::ns:Order/ns:Address", nsmgr).ChildNodes;

        foreach (XmlNode xmlAddressNode in xmlAddressNodes)
        {
            switch (xmlAddressNode.Name)
            {
                case "AddressLine": 
                    if (buyerAddressLine1 == "" && xmlAddressNode.InnerText.Length >= 1)
                    {
                        buyerAddressLine1 = xmlAddressNode.InnerText;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (buyerAddressLine2 == "" && xmlAddressNode.InnerText.Length >= 1)
                    {
                        buyerAddressLine2 = xmlAddressNode.InnerText;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (buyerAddressLine3 == "" && xmlAddressNode.InnerText.Length >= 1)
                    {
                        buyerAddressLine3 = xmlAddressNode.InnerText;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (buyerAddressLine4 == "" && xmlAddressNode.InnerText.Length >= 1)
                    {
                        buyerAddressLine4 = xmlAddressNode.InnerText;
                        break;
                    }

                    break;

                case "PostCode":
                    buyerPostCode = xmlAddressNode.InnerText;
                    break;
            }
        }

        // To Do loop through each DespatchLine element
        // DespatchLine
        XmlNodeList xmlDespatchLineNodes = xmlnode[i].SelectSingleNode("descendant::ns:DespatchLine", nsmgr).ChildNodes;

        foreach (XmlNode xmlDespatchLineNode in xmlDespatchLineNodes)
        {
            switch (xmlDespatchLineNode.Name)
            {
                case "LineNumber":
                    lineNumber = xmlDespatchLineNode.InnerText;
                    break;
            }                    
        }

        XmlNodeList xmlDespatchLineReferenceNodes = xmlnode[i].SelectSingleNode("descendant::ns:DespatchLine/ns:DespatchLineReferences", nsmgr).ChildNodes;

        foreach (XmlNode xmlDespatchLineReferenceNode in xmlDespatchLineReferenceNodes)
        {
            switch (xmlDespatchLineReferenceNode.Name)
            {
                case "CustomersOrderReference":
                    customersOrderReference = xmlDespatchLineReferenceNode.InnerText;
                    break;
            }
        }

        XmlNodeList xmlDespatchLineProductNodes = xmlnode[i].SelectSingleNode("descendant::ns:DespatchLine/ns:Product", nsmgr).ChildNodes;

        foreach (XmlNode xmlDespatchLineProductNode in xmlDespatchLineProductNodes)
        {
            switch (xmlDespatchLineProductNode.Name)
            {
                case "SuppliersProductCode":
                   suppliersProductCode = xmlDespatchLineProductNode.InnerText;
                   break;

                case "ConsumerUnitCode":
                   consumerUnitCode = xmlDespatchLineProductNode.InnerText;
                   break;

                case "Description":
                   description = xmlDespatchLineProductNode.InnerText;
                   break;
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Write to the database");
        db.UpdateDatabase(orderNo,
                buyerAddressLine1, buyerAddressLine2,
                buyerAddressLine3, buyerAddressLine4,
                buyerPostCode,
                lineNumber,
                customersOrderReference,
                suppliersProductCode,
                consumerUnitCode,
                description);
    }

    fs.Close();  // Close the connection so no processes are left open.
}

public class WriteToDatabase
{
    public void UpdateDatabase
    (
                string orderNo,
                string buyerAddressLine1,
                string buyerAddressLine2,
                string buyerAddressLine3,
                string buyerAddressLine4,
                string buyerPostCode,
                string lineNumber,
                string customersOrderReference,
                string suppliersProductCode,
                string consumerUnitCode,
                string description
            )
        {
            string sqConString = "data source=TestBox;initial catalog=TestPlay;integrated security=True";
            string sqCommand = "spPopulateTest";
            using (SqlConnection sqCon = new SqlConnection(sqConString))
            {
                sqCon.Open();
                {
                    using (SqlCommand sqCom = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        sqCom.CommandText = sqCommand;
                        sqCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        sqCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("OrderNo", orderNo));

                        sqCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("BuyerAddressLine1", buyerAddressLine1));
                        sqCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("BuyerAddressLine2", buyerAddressLine2));
                        sqCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("BuyerAddressLine3", buyerAddressLine3));
                        sqCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("BuyerAddressLine4", buyerAddressLine4));
                        sqCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("BuyerPostCode", buyerPostCode));

                        sqCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LineNumber", lineNumber));
                        sqCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("CustomersOrderReference", customersOrderReference));

                        sqCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SuppliersProductCode", suppliersProductCode));
                        sqCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ConsumerUnitCode", consumerUnitCode));
                        sqCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Description", description));

                        sqCom.Connection = sqCon;
                        sqCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                sqCon.Close();      
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a for loop around the despatch line element to solve the issue.